# how to use circle class in jgrasp

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, jgrasp

Hello I'm currently learning Object and Classes, to be more specific it is using classes. From what I understand when you create a class you should be able to create multiple objects with in. I've been testing some codes to see if it would work and it does. But when I try to put in my own made up code JGRASP tells me that it cannot find the symbol. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong since I'm reading and copying from a book. Can you help? AlternativeCircle part in the code is from the book while Circle is something I wrote to see if it would work.

```html
public class CircleTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

   AlternativeCircle circle1 = new AlternativeCircle();
      System.out.println("The area of the circle of radius "
         + circle1.radius + " is " + circle1.getArea());
         
         
  Circle circle2 = new Circle(25);
   System.out.println("The area of the circle of radius " 
      + circle2.radius + " is " + circle2.getArea());
   
}
}
```

Comment: Your code is in java not in javascript. Please remove tag so right people can answer.

Comment: Please post the code you wrote for the `Circle` class, and the exact error message you're getting. Also, this question is tagged javascript, but the code looks like java.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow so I'm not really sure whats what.